# Knockout and TypeScript: using generic class in component registration

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout (3.4.0) with typescript and I come across with problem that I can't register knockout component with view model of generic type. Is there a way to use generic class in such cases?

```
ko.components.register("button-update", {
    viewModel: ButtonViewModel<UpdateButtonBehavior>,
    template: /**/
});

export class ButtonViewModel<T extends ButtonBehavior> {
    constructor(opts) { /**/ }
}

export abstract class ButtonBehavior {}

export class UpdateButtonBehavior extends ButtonBehavior {}
```

Update:

The problem is that typescript compiler shows error: "Operator < can not be applied to types ButtonViewModel and UpdateButtonBehavior>.

My aim is to register some different buttons with own custom behaviors derived from `ButtonBehavior`

```
ko.components.register("button-save", {
    viewModel: ButtonViewModel<SaveButtonBehavior>,
    template: /**/
});

ko.components.register("button-delete", {
    viewModel: ButtonViewModel<DeleteButtonBehavior>,
    template: /**/
});
```

where

```
export class SaveButtonBehavior extends ButtonBehavior {}

export class DeleteButtonBehavior extends ButtonBehavior {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` is for type

```
ko.components.register("button-update", {
    viewModel: ButtonViewModel<UpdateButtonBehavior>,
    template: /**/
});

export class ButtonViewModel<T> extends ButtonBehavior { /**/ }

export abstract class ButtonBehavior {
    constructor(opts) { /**/ }
}

export class UpdateButtonBehavior {
    constructor(opts) { /**/ }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for ambiguity in question. I meant that the problem within component registration - typescript compile gets error that "Operator < can not be applied to types ButtonViewModel and UpdateButtonBehavior>. Going to update question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for the knockout component registration, which indicates the ViewModel has to be one of these 3 options:

- A constructor function
- A shared object instance
- A createViewModel factory function

(See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#specifying-a-viewmodel)

By using `ButtonViewModel<SaveButtonBehavior>`, you're trying to assign it a **Type**, which is only known to Typescript and has no Javascript equivalent.

### Solution 1: leave out the specific type

```
ko.components.register("button-save", {
    viewModel: ButtonViewModel,
    template: /**/
});

ko.components.register("button-delete", {
    viewModel: ButtonViewModel,
    template: /**/
});
```

### Solution 2: setup a createViewModel factory function

```
ko.components.register('button-save', {
    viewModel: {
        createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
            return new ButtonViewModel<SaveButtonBehavior>(params);
        }
    },
    template: /**/
});

ko.components.register('button-delete', {
    viewModel: {
        createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
            return new ButtonViewModel<DeleteButtonBehavior>(params);
        }
    },
    template: /**/
});
```

### Solution 3: Create a single object instance for each of the types

Note that this scenario will only work if you'll only ever want to create a single component of each type, which is **highly unlikely**.

```
ko.components.register('button-save', {
    viewModel: { 
        instance: new ButtonViewModel<SaveButtonBehavior>();
    },
    template: /**/
});

ko.components.register('button-delete', {
    viewModel: {
        instance: new ButtonViewModel<DeleteButtonBehavior>();
    },
    template: /**/
});
```